# problemas com chave estrangeira ao selecionar os itens

Tags: php, mysql, chave-estrangeira

Bom, estou tentando selecionar todos os itens de duas listagens separadas, porém sem sucesso, estou usando:

> Query

```
select t*, d.id as id_discvinculada from textos as t join disciplinas as d on t.id_discvinculada = d.id
```

> Função

```
function listagemTextos($conexao){
    $textos = array();
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select t*, d.nome_disciplina as id_discvinculada from textos as t join disciplinas as d on t.id_discvinculada = d.id");
    while($texto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
        array_push($textos, $texto);
    }
    return $textos;
}
```

> Chamada da função

```
<?php

$textos = listagemTextos($conexao);

foreach ($textos as $texto){
    ?>

    <div>
        <div>
            <h4><?= $texto["titulo"] ?></h4>
            <label><?= $texto["id_discvinculada"] ?></label>
            <ul>
                <span>Opções</span>
                <li>Alterar</li>
                <li><a href="logicas/logica-remover_texto.php?id=<?= $texto['id']?>">Remove</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <?= $texto["texto"] ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

> Disciplinas

[image: Disciplinas]

> Textos

[image: Textos Table]

> Warning

```
Warning
: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in
C:\xampp\htdocs\dev_port\historia\logicas\banco_textos.php
on line
7
```

Como adiciono a Foreign Key, e a utilizo para que eu possa exibir os itens corretamente na chamada da função ?

Comment: Aparentemente faltou um ponto em sua consulta em `t*`, logo no início. Você pode verificar o erro utilizando a função [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.error.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta alterar sua `query` para isso:

```
select t.*, d.nome_disciplina as id_discvinculada from textos t
join disciplinas d on t.id_discvinculada = d.id
```